# Array for each array row PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, row

I have an `array` with name `$items` like this:

```
array(2) { 

[0]=> array(8) { ["item_regel"]=> int(0) ["item_id"]=> string(2) "82" ["item_naam"]=> string(21) "Bureauschermen staand" ["item_uitvoering"]=> string(12) "100 x 200 cm" ["item_afmeting"]=> NULL ["item_kleur"]=> string(11) "Transparant" ["item_aantal"]=> string(1) "2" ["item_opmerking"]=> string(18) "Ik wil mijn logo 2" } 

[1]=> array(8) { ["item_regel"]=> int(1) ["item_id"]=> string(3) "226" ["item_naam"]=> string(33) "Instructieborden Dibond aluminium" ["item_uitvoering"]=> string(10) "50 x 50 cm" ["item_afmeting"]=> NULL ["item_kleur"]=> string(5) "Blauw" ["item_aantal"]=> string(1) "2" ["item_opmerking"]=> string(4) "test" } 

}
```

I found this code to prefill a gravity form list field:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_list_one', 'itsg_prefill_list_one' );
function itsg_prefill_list_one( $value ) {
    $list_array = array(
        //List row
        array(
            "Product" => "Product",
            "Afmeting" => "Good",
            "Uitvoering" => "Product",
            "Kleur" => "Product",
            "Aantal" => "Product",
            "Opmerking" => "Product",
        ),
        //List row
        array(
            "Product" => "Product",
            "Afmeting" => "Good",
            "Uitvoering" => "Product",
            "Kleur" => "Product",
            "Aantal" => "Product",
            "Opmerking" => "Product",
        ),
    );
    return $list_array;
}
```

Now this `function` is filled with fixed `values`. I want to do a `'List row'` `foreach` row inside the `array` above.

I tried this but it won't work:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_list_one', 'itsg_prefill_list_one' );
function itsg_prefill_list_one( $value ) {
$items = $_SESSION["wishlist"];
    $list_array = array(
     foreach ($items as $keys => $values) {
       array(
            "Product" => $values["item_naam"],
            "Afmeting" => $values["item_afmeting"],
            "Uitvoering" => $values["item_uitvoering"],
            "Kleur" => $values["item_kleur"],
            "Aantal" => $values["item_aantal"],
            "Opmerking" => $values["item_opmerking"],
        ),
     }
);
    return $list_array;
}
```

Comment: Then you should have a go. If, when you have made an attempt and it does not work, come on back and ask for help on that specific issue

Comment: Editted my code with what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop add items to the array from the looped array

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_list_one', 'itsg_prefill_list_one' );
function itsg_prefill_list_one( $value ) {

    foreach ($_SESSION["wishlist"] as $keys => $values) {
        $list_array[] = [
                        "Product" => $values["item_naam"],
                        "Afmeting" => $values["item_afmeting"],
                        "Uitvoering" => $values["item_uitvoering"],
                        "Kleur" => $values["item_kleur"],
                        "Aantal" => $values["item_aantal"],
                        "Opmerking" => $values["item_opmerking"],
                        ];
    }
    return $list_array;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. The values like `"Product"` ,` "Afmeting"` etc needs to be set fixed. Only what comes after the `=>` is needs to be out of the `array`

Comment: Is that better, its not difficult doing that